# I am not able to include NTDDk header

Tags: function, kernel, wdk

I am trying to include the header `<ntddk.h>` but it's unreconized. Do I need to change any project settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the a windows driver development SDK. I suppose you already installed it.

WDK (latest version): http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/WDK/WDKpkg.mspx

Then you just need to use the build environment (command line) to build the drivers. If you are not making driver development, then I do not know what you want to do with ntddk.h

Comment: yes,I have already installed..I included in the additional dependencies in the project settings..I got an error "unable to open c:/programfiles.obj"

Comment: Are you sure you use the build environment "Checked Build Environment" for example. The include paths should then be set correctly. I use NOT to install the WDK inside a path with spaces, maybe you did and this causes the trouble?